# How to use remote bitcoind with docker

Tags: core-lightning

I want to use multiple nodes with the same remote bitcoind. E.g. my node on my desktop, my node on digital ocean, my node on Google cloud ...

I don't want to run everywhere a full bitcoind and pay for the disk space. 
I currently check the option to use btcpayserver (docker) on Google cloud as well. Again, it would need bitcoind.

Any hints welcome.

Answer (score 1):

c-lightning internally calls `bitcoin-cli` and will pass a couple of commandline arguments to it. These arguments are all prefixed with `--bitcoin-*` and will match the ones that `bitcoin-cli` accepts.

So for your use-case you first need to make sure that `bitcoin-cli` is available on the machine that you will be running the c-lightning instances on. If it isn't you can simply use the Bitcoin PPA to install (but not run) `bitcoind` which will also install `bitcoin-cli` (assuming you're using a debian based OS):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
```

For a remote `bitcoind` you need to specify the following arguments:

- `--bitcoin-rpcconnect=<bitcoind-ip:port>` this tells `bitcoin-cli` to connect to a remote `bitcoind` instance instead of trying `localhost:8332` (make sure `bitcoind` is configured with `-rpcallowip=<ip>`, where `<ip>` is the machine you'll be running c-lightning on)
- `--bitcoin-rpcuser=<username>` the username configured with `bitcoind`
- `--bitcoin-rpcpassword=<password>` the password configured with `bitcoind`

In any case I'd suggest running `bitcoin-cli --bitcoin-rpcconnect=<bitcoind-ip:port> --bitcoin-rpcuser=<username> --bitcoin-rpcpassword=<password>` from the command line on the c-lightning machine to verify that `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli` are configured correctly.